# Induced representations built on sections of an associated vector bundle. Questions on notations

Tags: representation-theory, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, functors, equivariant-maps

Consider a group $\,G\,$, a vector space $\,{\mathbb{V}}\,$, and a space $\,{\cal{L}}^G\,$ of functions $\varphi$ on this group:
$$
 {\cal{L}}^G\;=\;\left\{~\varphi~\Big{|}~~~\varphi:\,~G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}\,\right\}~~.
 $$
Let $\,D\,$ be a representation of a subgroup $\,K\leq G\,$ in the said vector space:
$$
 D~:\quad K~\longrightarrow~GL({\mathbb{V}})\;\;.\qquad\qquad\qquad \label{1}\tag{1}
 $$

The induced representation $\,D(K)\uparrow G\,=\,\operatorname{Ind}_K^GD\,$ is implemented with the left translations
$$
  U_g\varphi(x)=\varphi({g^{-1}}x)~~,\qquad g,\,x\in G\;, 
  $$
acting in the subspace comprising Mackey functions (those satisfying the equivariance condition):
$$
  \left\{~\varphi~\Big{|}~~~\varphi:\,~G\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}\;,\quad \varphi(xk)=D^{-1}(k)\,\varphi(x)\,\right\}~\subset~{\cal{L}}^G~~,~~~x\in G~~,~~~k\in K~~.~~~~~\label{2}\tag{2}
  $$

QUESTION 1.

For the space of Mackey functions, I saw two notations:  $\;\operatorname{Hom}_K(G,\,{\mathbb{V}})\;$ and $\;\operatorname{Map}_K(G,\,{\mathbb{V}})\;$.

What is the difference between these notations?

Are both equally acceptable?

QUESTION 2.

Space \eqref{2} of Mackey functions is a section over the associated vector bundle over the left coset space $G/K$. Consequently, the space of Mackey functions splits into $\,|G/K|\,$ subspaces:
$$
 \operatorname{Map}_K(G,\,{\mathbb{V}})\,=\;\bigoplus_X \,
 \operatorname{Map}_K(X,\,{\mathbb{V}})
 \;\;,\qquad\qquad
$$
where $X\in G/K$ is a left coset, while the fiber above this coset,
$$
 \operatorname{Map}_K(X,\,{\mathbb{V}})\,=\;\left\{\,\varphi_{_X}\;\Big{|}\;\varphi_{_X}\,=\;P_{_X}\,\varphi\; \right\}\;\;,\;\;\;\;
 $$
comprises such functions $\varphi_{_X}$ that each $\varphi_{_X}$ coincides with $\varphi$ on a coset $X$ and is zero outside it:
$$
 \varphi_{_X}\,\equiv\;P_{_X}\,\varphi\;=\;
 \left\{
 \begin{array}{lll}
 \varphi(g)\;\;\;&\mbox{for}\quad g\in X\;\;,\\
 0\;\;\;\;\;&\mbox{for}\quad g\notin X\;\;.
 \end{array}
 \right.
 $$
Mind that each such $\varphi_{_X}$ is a Mackey function, because $\, D(k)\,\varphi_{_X}(g)=\varphi_{_X}(g\, k^{-1})$ holds for it.

Now, the question:

With a left coset $X$ understood as a point of the base $G/K$, was it correct of me to employ the notation $\;\operatorname{Map}_K(X,\,{\mathbb{V}})\;$ for the fiber corresponding to $X\,$?

Could I have used for this fiber also the notation $\;\operatorname{Hom}_K(X,\,{\mathbb{V}})\;$?